# My Python3 Library provides a Wrapper around the Popular espeak TTS

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, library

My code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import platform

class Speaker:
    """
    Speaker class for differentiating different speech properties.
    """

    def setVoice(self, voice):
        self.voice = voice

    def setWPM(self, wpm):
        self.wpm = wpm

    def setPitch(self, pitch):
        self.pitch = pitch

    def setProperties(self, voice="en", wpm=120, pitch=80):
        self.setVoice(voice)
        self.setWPM(wpm)
        self.setPitch(pitch)

    def __init__(self, voice="en", wpm=120, pitch=80):
        self.prevproc = None
        self.setProperties(voice, wpm, pitch)
        self.executable = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) +
                              "/espeak.exe" if platform.system() == 'Windows'
                              else os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/espeak"

    def generateCommand(self, phrase):
        cmd = [
            self.executable,
            "--path=.",
            "-v", self.voice,
            "-p", self.pitch,
            "-s", self.wpm,
            phrase
        ]
        cmd = [str(x) for x in cmd]
        return cmd

    def say(self, phrase, wait4prev=False):
        cmd=self.generateCommand(phrase)
        if wait4prev:
            try: self.prevproc.wait()
            except AttributeError: pass
        else:
            try: self.prevproc.terminate()
            except AttributeError: pass
        self.prevproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, executable=self.executable,
                            cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

How can the above code be improved?

Find it on GitHub: https://github.com/sayak-brm/espeak4py

Usage:

```
import espeak4py
import time

print('Testing espeak4py\n')

mySpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker()

mySpeaker.say('Testing', wait4prev=True)

print('Testing wait4prev')

mySpeaker.say('Hello, World!')
time.sleep(1)
mySpeaker.say('Interrupted!')
time.sleep(3)

mySpeaker.say('Hello, World!')
time.sleep(1)
mySpeaker.say('Not Interrupted.', wait4prev=True)
time.sleep(3)

print('Testing pitch')

myHighPitchedSpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker(pitch=120)
myHighPitchedSpeaker.say('I am a demo of the say function')
time.sleep(4)

print('Testing wpm')

myFastSpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker(wpm=140)
myFastSpeaker.say('I am a demo of the say function')
time.sleep(4)

print('Testing voice')

mySpanishSpeaker = espeak4py.Speaker(voice='es')
mySpanishSpeaker.say('Hola. Como estas?')

print('Testing Completed.')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.PEP8**

**Naming**

In python functions/methods/variables are using underscore as a naming separator, but not a camelCase.

**Quotes**

You should pick one double or single quotes and use it everywhere that is a general rule, I prefer single ones so I've changed a code as I like, but you might want to use double, just follow one way to do that.

Please read code styling guide aka [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

**2.Class definition**

**Methods order**

I prefer to have `__init__` and `__new__` as first methods defined by class, this gives you better image on class and what it does and what it got. This is not a strong rule, but most of people and libraries are following it.

**Properties definition**

Most of the times you want to have all your properties defined in **init**, 
again that is not a strong rule, but in this particular case, I would define them inside `__init__` instead of having a separate method to do that. If fact you I don't see much of use of your `setProperties` method, so I would just modify object attributes directly here if I would need it. Since there are no logics inside those methods except for changing an attribute to a value passed into it.

**3.Improvements**

I'm not a big fan of try:catch:pass statements you can avoid them with pre-conditions: so your `say` method can be modified like this:

```
def say(self, phrase, wait4prev=False):
    cmd = self.generate_command(phrase)
    if self.prevproc:
        if wait4prev:
            self.prevproc.wait()
        else:
            self.prevproc.terminate()
    self.prevproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Note: you don't need to pass executable explicitly since it's already a part of your cmd param.

So in the end what we have is this:

```
import os
import platform
import subprocess


class Speaker:
    """
    Speaker class for differentiating different speech properties.
    """
    def __init__(self, voice='en', wpm=120, pitch=80):
        self.prevproc = None
        self.voice = voice
        self.wpm = wpm
        self.pitch = pitch

        executable = 'espeak.exe' if platform.system() == 'Windows' else 'espeak'
        self.executable = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), executable)

    def generate_command(self, phrase):
        cmd = [
            self.executable,
            '--path=.',
            '-v', self.voice,
            '-p', self.pitch,
            '-s', self.wpm,
            phrase
        ]
        cmd = [str(x) for x in cmd]
        return cmd

    def say(self, phrase, wait4prev=False):
        cmd = self.generate_command(phrase)
        if self.prevproc:
            if wait4prev:
                self.prevproc.wait()
            else:
                self.prevproc.terminate()
        self.prevproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: I learnt a lot about Python today, thanks to you. I'll be sure to read up more about the PEP8 (I didn't know that something like that existed).